# What and where to get assemblies to make Saxon-HE source code work in VS 2015?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, saxon

I've downloaded the [Saxon-HE source code](http://www.saxonica.com/download/opensource.xml) and tried to build it on .NET Framework 4.5.2 but it's looking for assemblies which I don't know what and where to get.

Here are some of the errors shown:

[image]

[image]

The assemblies already in reference are the below:

[image]

What other assemblies do I need to add, and where do I get these? My google-fu has failed me for an hour now.

Answer (score 0):

I googled the packages and found in which jars these are found using the Maven Repository as well as from the [Saxon documentation](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/about/installationdotnet.html) and downloaded them. Also discovered that I can't directly load a jar file as a dll assembly. So I looked for a way to convert the jar to a C# dll.

After downloading the saxon jar files first, I downloaded the IKVM bin file from [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=69637), and used IKVM.NET bytecode compiler [ikvmc](http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/ikvmc.html) to generate the dll file from the saxon jar file with the following command in windows power shell:

> .\ikvmc saxon9he.jar -target:library

and then added the resulting dll to the project reference.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially there are two components to Saxon on .NET. There's saxon9he.dll, which is the Java code cross-compiled to a .NET assembly, and there's saxon9api.dll which is C# code providing a .NET API. Normal applications only need to reference the saxon9api DLL (which itself references the saxon9he DLL). But if you want to dig deeper, or if you want to recompile the source of saxon9api, then you'll need your project to include the saxon9he DLL. If you want to go even further and modify the core Saxon code then you'll need to rebuild from Java source code - but it's very unlikely you really need to do that. I can't see any reason why you would want to re-run the IKVMC conversion of the JAR to a DLL unless you've changed the Java code - just use the DLL that Saxonica issues.

Comment: Thanks very much for giving a helpful context. This is my first time to use Saxon.